# The curious case of /public/assets/ in a Meteor project

Tags: meteor, build, hierarchy

In my Meteor 1.10.2 project, I have created a folder called `assets` inside the `/public/` folder. When the Meteor application is built, I find this `assets` folder has been copied to these locations, as a direct child of the `web.browser...` folders:

```
/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/assets/
/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser.legacy/assets
```

However, if I rename the folder to `Assets` (or if I give it any other name), when the application is built, I find it deeper in, inside the `app` folder at:

```
/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/Assets/
/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser.legacy/app/Assets/
```

What is the logic behind this? What is the intention? What are the best practices for working with a folder at `/public/assets/`? Are there any other words that are given special treatment when used as names for folders inside the `/public/` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, this behaviour is specifically due to meteor tools bundler:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%401.10.2/tools/isobuild/bundler.js#L719-L725

```js
  setTargetPathFromRelPath(relPath) {
    // XXX hack
    if (relPath.match(/^(packages|assets|dynamic)\//)) {
      this.targetPath = relPath;
    } else {
      this.targetPath = files.pathJoin('app', relPath);
    }
```

Therefore we can see that there are 3 special directory names that exhibit this special behaviour:

- packages
- assets
- dynamic

Example with public assets:

[image: public assets]

These assets bundled in build:

[image: assets copied in build]

For "packages", while we can understand that this is how Meteor ships the static assets of packages (i.e. when they call [`api.addAssets()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#PackageAPI-addAssets), we can also see that there is a potential for collision, in the (however unlikely) case we use a pathname like "public/packages/my-package-name".

As for "assets", the initial name was "static", but I do not think it was publicly documented either.

And for "dynamic", I do not know yet what is its exact purpose, but we can see that it serves its content as "javascript" type (at least SVG files), whereas the first 2 serve them as "text/plain".

[image: SVG file in dynamic served as javascript]

Answer (score 0):

What Meteor does is build your project multiple times. Once for legacy web browsers, and again for a modern browser, and also for other platforms such as IOS or Android. It does all this inside the .meteor/local folder as you have observed.

Meteor has the concept of a /private folder, which is similar to /public, except that Meteor thinks of them as `assets`. This might explain why your folder appears in different locations, depending on the name.

Personally I wouldn't worry too much about how Meteor handles files, unless you want to become a contributor, in which case you are welcome to poke around :)

Comment: Items placed in the `/private/` folder are found in `/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/app` and are not accessible from the browser. This is a different issue. The only thing that is common is the name `assets`. Information about `/private/` and the `Assets` global is openly available [on the Meteor site](https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html). I have not found any information about `/public/assets/` anywhere.